# How to map the JSON response to Html page using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

I am trying to map the data received in the JSON to my html page using the ng-repeat, but somehow its not producing the data on the front end.my html code is as follows:

```
ul ng-repeat="ScheduleData in viewScheduleData"<br/>
li{{ScheduleData.day}}<br/>
  ul<br/>
    li{{ScheduleData.time_start}}/li<br/>
    li{{ScheduleData.time_end}}/li<br/>
  /ul<br/>
  /li <br/>  
/ul<br/>
```

and my scheduleCtrl.js has the code as follows:

```
        Schedule.viewSchedule($scope.doctorprofile,function(data) {<br/>
                      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));<br/>
                      if (data.ResponseCode == 1) {<br/>
                        console.log("yes in");<br/>
                        $Scope.viewScheduleData = data.Result;<br/>
                      }});
```

I can see thee data coming through JSON stringify

Comment: What is inside `data.result` ? + `$scope` should be in lower case

Comment: Provide the json sample

Comment: Sorry but I got the answer, it was because i was not accessing the right object inside data.Result, instead was trying to access the elements directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with these

```
Schedule.viewSchedule($scope.doctorprofile,function(data) {
                  if (data.ResponseCode == 1) {
                    $scope.viewScheduleData = data;
                  }});
```

Answer (score 0):

$Scope needs to be changed to $scope. "s" should be small.
You need to give like this.and viewScheduleData should be an array.

```
<ul> ng-repeat="ScheduleData in viewScheduleData">
  <li>{{ScheduleData.day}}</li>
  <li>{{ScheduleData.time_start}}</li>
  <li>{{ScheduleData.time_end}}</li>
</ul>
```